# CSV Import: Does anyone know of any good CSV importing tools?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, csv

I have a few CSV's that need importing in my C# to SQL Server tables. I have done this before but found it pretty boring and tedious.

Does anyone know of any tools or methods to speed up this process?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

IF you need to do it via C# then take a look at [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CsvReaderAndWriter.aspx .

IF you want to do it via SQL (BULK INSERT) then see the walkthrough (including source) here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/ (MSDN reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

There is an easier option though by using the [SQL Server Import Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) interactively for a small number of files.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio, on the database under Right Click -> Tasks -> Import Data... can consume CSV files.

If you need to do it via C#, there are plenty of CSV readers and writers around:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CsvReaderAndWriter.aspx

From here it's only a short hop to a `DataTable` and `SqlBulkCopy`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute a `BULK INSERT` statement.

A quick google suggests these sites:

- [SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server « Journey to SQLAuthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)
- [BULK INSERT on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library is fantastic for doing this sort of stuff through code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the csv is structured in this way:

- One row is one entry
- The split-character to devide the fields is in the first position of every row.

I would do it in that way:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("<CSV-File>");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(new[] { line[0] }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really add the records to the db, though.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is Microsoft's ETL tool and handles CSV files easily.